# Call fnServerData in DataTables 1.10

Tags: javascript, datatables

So I'm looking at this [example](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3931/server-side-filtering-on-specific-columns-with-input-and-select) and am trying to make it work for me.

I want to add the select options to my table when I use server side processing. Since I have only used version 1.10 I always get confused when I see this old API.

I don't understand how I can use this function in 1.10:

```
"sAjaxSource": "../examples_support/server_processing.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        /* ... additional variables ... */
        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
            /* Create the select elements on the first run */
            if ( json.sEcho == 1 )
            {
                $("tfoot th").each( function (i) {
                    /* Insert the select menu */
                    this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(json.select[i]);

                    /* Add the event listener for the newly created element */
                    $('select', this).change( function () {
                        oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
                    } );
                } );
            }

            /* DataTables callback */
            fnCallback(json)
        } );
    }
```

The [converting guide](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) just lists `fnServerData` as `ajax`.

This is my initialization code:

```
$('#dataTables-outputTest').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/TestData/data-source",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "thing1",
          "searchable": true},
        { "data": "thing2",
         "searchable": true},
         ...
        { "data": "link",
         "searchable": false,
         "orderable": false},
    ],
    "initComplete": function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
});
```

How do I use that function and how do I have to rewrite it to work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I didn't understand what fnServerData did. It can be used to send additional data to the server from the client. So it's the oposite of what I'm trying to do.

I managed to do this by using this code:

```
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/MyApp/data-source',
        data: function ( data ) {
            data.someKey =  "someValue";
        },
    },
```

Then when I print my request on the server I find a new object in the dictionary:

```
'someKey': ['someValue']
```